# easier way to join two elements in an existing array as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, join

I'm using Codeigniter and getting the input from post. The post contain an array like this:

```
$post_array = {
      'name'         =>    'john',
      'year_start'   =>    1992,
      'year_end'     =>    2000,
      ...     
    }
```

I wanted to join year_start and year_end as a new array call year_range so to replace the two elements in the original post array.

```
$new_array = {
      'name'         =>    'john',
      'year_range'   =>    ['year_start' =>   1992,
                            'year_end'   =>   2000],
      ...

    }
```

I can do this by typing out the entire new array like this:

```
$name       = $this->input->post('name');
$year_start = $this->input->post('year_start');
$year_end   = $this->input->post('year_end');

$new_array = {
      'name'         =>    $name,
      'year_range'   =>    ['year_start' =>   $year_start,
                            'year_end'   =>   $year_end ],
      ...                
    }
```

But it will be tedious if the post array gets long. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making your form elements:

```
name="year_range[year_start]"

name="year_range[year_end]"
```

EDITED: shouldn't have quotes inside the []

Comment: my post array was passed in by an ajax post, it gives me syntax error when I use these name while preparing the object.